# Selenium2 (WebDriver) using Java fails when browser window is not focused

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, automated-tests

My Selenium Java Webdriver tests are failing when they start if I don't click on the browser page that is being opened.

The following crash is caused from an `ElementNotVisibleException`, obviously.

This was not a big issue until now that I have to put them in a Jenkins CI machine.

Can any body help by providing possible solution or suggestion?

Comment: Once you open the browser window, have you added the selenium command viz. selenium.windowFocus() to focus on the window?

Comment: are you using Selenium RC?

Answer (score 1):

For Selenium RC:

```
selenium.windowFocus();
selenium.windowMaximize();
```

For WebDriver (Selenium 2):

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```